# Package folder named 'case' in Android Studio causes hilt error

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-hilt

I found a very strange behavior in Android Studio. When I try to create a package `case` then Android Studio marks the folder as folder and not as a package:

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio showing package folders and only the folder case does not have a dot on the icon]

This is not just a UI problem. When I place a class inside the case folder and I want to use dependency injection to inject an instance of this class into a view model, the class is not found by the hilt compiler and leads to an error:

```
@HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor.
```

And the hilt generated java file is missing the class in the case folder from the constructor.

However, I can use the class normally without dependency injection in the app, so kotlin in general seems to be ok with it.

I would have blamed it as a hilt bug, but since Android Studio recognizes the folder differently I kind of curious if somebody knows why.

Comment: `case` is a Java keyword, so I am not at all surprised that you are having problems with it in a Java package name.

Comment: I'm surprised that this causes only problems with hilt and not with anything else. And that Android Studio didn't show a warning like "using Java keywords is not recommended" when it even shows the folder differently. - Thanks for the refresher!

Comment: The reason it causes problems with Dagger is that Dagger generates Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Java keyword. `case` is a keyword.

For more keys you can check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html